# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Type error

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

```
async def balance(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users where id={author.id}")
    time.sleep(3)
    if cursor.fetchone()==None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ({author.id}, '{author.name}', '<@{author.id}>', 0, 1)")
        connection.commit()
        bal=cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", (author.id,)).fetchone()[0]
        await ctx.send('Balance:{0} :coin:'.format(bal))
    elif cursor.fetchone()==True:
        author = ctx.message.author
        bal=cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", (author.id,)).fetchone()[0]
        await ctx.send('Balance:{0} :coin:'.format(bal))
    else:
        await ctx.send('Error, try again later')
```

I was writing code for an economics bot in discord, and came across this error.

The error is here:

```
bal=cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", (author.id,)).fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It seems fetchone() return `None` but you are dealing with the `None` like a list (e.g., None[0])

Comment: if `x` is "not subscriptable", it means you can't index it like `x[0]` - you can't index `None` like `None[0]` and so the error is thrown when `.fetchone()` can't fetch anything and returns `None`.

Comment: I removed [0] and a new error occurred. When I enter a command, it gives me that the balance is [None], despite the fact that I added a way to earn money.

Comment: it means your query is incorrect, try fixing that

Comment: I do not know how to fix it, I checked all the queries, everything seems to be correct, but when I enter the "bal" command, it says "error, try later" to me.
Here is the command that creates the table: cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INT, nickname TEXT, mention TEXT, money INT )')

Comment: Also, this could be vulnerable to SQL injection, as discord allows ;) characters in names and the SQL query is directly constructed from this.